# Running ad-hoc SQL code on separate servers without Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to build a monitoring solution (results of stored procedures are sent via email) using stored procedures in SQL Server.

We have about 100 different servers, and linked Servers are not configured due to security.

I have deployed a stored procedure to each server using SSMS central management server. (If DB mail was enabled on all systems, I would send the output of these SPs directly to our DBAs, but the mail is only enabled on the CMS server.)

How do I get the output of these stored procedures when Linked Servers are not enabled?

I have tried to run the stored procedure through Linked Servers, but I am getting Kerebos errors - our system is too locked down and there is too much bureaucracy in getting this changed.

The pseudocode of my logic is below. The main issue I am facing right now relates to this portion of the code:

```
  SELECT *  
    FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=BBMAG552;Trusted_Connection=yes;',  
         'EXEC master.dbo.usp_sizing '''database''') AS a;
```

Full code below:

```
-- Pseduocode

--Build list of all servers registered in CMS
SELECT DISTINCT groups.name AS 'Server Group Name'
     ,svr.server_name AS 'Server Name'
FROM msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_server_groups_internal groups 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_registered_servers_internal svr
 ON groups.server_group_id = svr.server_group_id;
GO

-- execute the stored procedure against list of all servers using a
-- sp_MSforeachdb 

SELECT *  
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=BBMAG552;Trusted_Connection=yes;',  
     'EXEC master.dbo.usp_sizing '''database''') AS a; 



-- This script is run on all our servers.
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Sizing @Granularity VARCHAR(10) = NULL, @Database_Name sysname = NULL AS   
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(5000)   

IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE NAME = '##Results')    
   BEGIN    
       DROP TABLE ##Results    
   END   

CREATE TABLE ##Results ([Database Name] sysname, 
[File Name] sysname, 
[Physical Name] NVARCHAR(260),
[File Type] VARCHAR(4), 
[Total Size in Mb] INT, 
[Available Space in Mb] INT, 
[Growth Units] VARCHAR(15), 
[Max File Size in Mb] INT)   

SELECT @SQL =    
'USE [?] INSERT INTO ##Results([Database Name], [File Name], [Physical Name],    
[File Type], [Total Size in Mb], [Available Space in Mb],    
[Growth Units], [Max File Size in Mb])    
SELECT DB_NAME(),   
[name] AS [File Name],    
physical_name AS [Physical Name],    
[File Type] =    
CASE type   
WHEN 0 THEN ''Data'''    
+   
           'WHEN 1 THEN ''Log'''   
+   
       'END,   
[Total Size in Mb] =   
CASE ceiling([size]/128)    
WHEN 0 THEN 1   
ELSE ceiling([size]/128)   
END,   
[Available Space in Mb] =    
CASE ceiling([size]/128)   
WHEN 0 THEN (1 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY([name], ''SpaceUsed''' + ') as int) /128)   
ELSE (([size]/128) - CAST(FILEPROPERTY([name], ''SpaceUsed''' + ') as int) /128)   
END,   
[Growth Units]  =    
CASE [is_percent_growth]    
WHEN 1 THEN CAST(growth AS varchar(20)) + ''%'''   
+   
           'ELSE CAST(growth*8/1024 AS varchar(20)) + ''Mb'''   
+   
       'END,   
[Max File Size in Mb] =    
CASE [max_size]   
WHEN -1 THEN NULL   
WHEN 268435456 THEN NULL   
ELSE [max_size]   
END   
FROM sys.database_files   
ORDER BY [File Type], [file_id]'   

--Print the command to be issued against all databases   
PRINT @SQL   

--Run the command against each database   
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQL   

--UPDATE ##Results SET [Free Space %] = [Available Space in Mb]/[Total Size in Mb] * 100   

--Return the Results   
--If @Database_Name is NULL:   
IF @Database_Name IS NULL   
   BEGIN   
       IF @Granularity = 'Database'   
           BEGIN   
               SELECT    
               T.[Database Name],   
               T.[Total Size in Mb] AS [DB Size (Mb)],   
               T.[Available Space in Mb] AS [DB Free (Mb)],   
               T.[Consumed Space in Mb] AS [DB Used (Mb)],   
               D.[Total Size in Mb] AS [Data Size (Mb)],   
               D.[Available Space in Mb] AS [Data Free (Mb)],   
               D.[Consumed Space in Mb] AS [Data Used (Mb)],   
               CEILING(CAST(D.[Available Space in Mb] AS decimal(10,1))/D.[Total Size in Mb]*100) AS [Data Free %],   
               L.[Total Size in Mb] AS [Log Size (Mb)],   
               L.[Available Space in Mb] AS [Log Free (Mb)],   
               L.[Consumed Space in Mb] AS [Log Used (Mb)],   
               CEILING(CAST(L.[Available Space in Mb] AS decimal(10,1))/L.[Total Size in Mb]*100) AS [Log Free %]   
               FROM    
                   (   
                   SELECT [Database Name],   
                       SUM([Total Size in Mb]) AS [Total Size in Mb],   
                       SUM([Available Space in Mb]) AS [Available Space in Mb],   
                       SUM([Total Size in Mb]-[Available Space in Mb]) AS [Consumed Space in Mb]    
                   FROM ##Results   
                   GROUP BY [Database Name]   
                   ) AS T   
                   INNER JOIN    
                   (   
                   SELECT [Database Name],   
                       SUM([Total Size in Mb]) AS [Total Size in Mb],   
                       SUM([Available Space in Mb]) AS [Available Space in Mb],   
                       SUM([Total Size in Mb]-[Available Space in Mb]) AS [Consumed Space in Mb]    
                   FROM ##Results   
                   WHERE ##Results.[File Type] = 'Data'   
                   GROUP BY [Database Name]   
                   ) AS D ON T.[Database Name] = D.[Database Name]   
                   INNER JOIN   
                   (   
                   SELECT [Database Name],   
                       SUM([Total Size in Mb]) AS [Total Size in Mb],   
                       SUM([Available Space in Mb]) AS [Available Space in Mb],   
                       SUM([Total Size in Mb]-[Available Space in Mb]) AS [Consumed Space in Mb]    
                   FROM ##Results   
                   WHERE ##Results.[File Type] = 'Log'   
                   GROUP BY [Database Name]   
                   ) AS L ON T.[Database Name] = L.[Database Name]   
               ORDER BY CEILING(CAST(D.[Available Space in Mb] AS decimal(10,1))/D.[Total Size in Mb]*100) 
           END   
   ELSE   
       BEGIN   
           SELECT [Database Name],   
               [File Name],   
               [Physical Name],   
               [File Type],   
               [Total Size in Mb] AS [DB Size (Mb)],   
               [Available Space in Mb] AS [DB Free (Mb)],   
               CEILING(CAST([Available Space in Mb] AS decimal(10,1)) / [Total Size in Mb]*100) AS [Free Space %],   
               [Growth Units],   
               [Max File Size in Mb] AS [Grow Max Size (Mb)]    
           FROM ##Results    
       END   
   END   

--Return the Results   
--If @Database_Name is provided   
ELSE   
   BEGIN   
       IF @Granularity = 'Database'   
           BEGIN   
               SELECT    
               T.[Database Name],   
               T.[Total Size in Mb] AS [DB Size (Mb)],   
               T.[Available Space in Mb] AS [DB Free (Mb)],   
               T.[Consumed Space in Mb] AS [DB Used (Mb)],   
               D.[Total Size in Mb] AS [Data Size (Mb)],   
               D.[Available Space in Mb] AS [Data Free (Mb)],   
               D.[Consumed Space in Mb] AS [Data Used (Mb)],   
               CEILING(CAST(D.[Available Space in Mb] AS decimal(10,1))/D.[Total Size in Mb]*100) AS [Data Free %],   
               L.[Total Size in Mb] AS [Log Size (Mb)],   
               L.[Available Space in Mb] AS [Log Free (Mb)],   
               L.[Consumed Space in Mb] AS [Log Used (Mb)],   
               CEILING(CAST(L.[Available Space in Mb] AS decimal(10,1))/L.[Total Size in Mb]*100) AS [Log Free %]   
               FROM    
                   (   
                   SELECT [Database Name],   
                       SUM([Total Size in Mb]) AS [Total Size in Mb],   
                       SUM([Available Space in Mb]) AS [Available Space in Mb],   
                       SUM([Total Size in Mb]-[Available Space in Mb]) AS [Consumed Space in Mb]    
                   FROM ##Results   
                   WHERE [Database Name] = @Database_Name   
                   GROUP BY [Database Name]   
                   ) AS T   
                   INNER JOIN    
                   (   
                   SELECT [Database Name],   
                       SUM([Total Size in Mb]) AS [Total Size in Mb],   
                       SUM([Available Space in Mb]) AS [Available Space in Mb],   
                       SUM([Total Size in Mb]-[Available Space in Mb]) AS [Consumed Space in Mb]    
                   FROM ##Results   
                   WHERE ##Results.[File Type] = 'Data'   
                       AND [Database Name] = @Database_Name   
                   GROUP BY [Database Name]   
                   ) AS D ON T.[Database Name] = D.[Database Name]   
                   INNER JOIN   
                   (   
                   SELECT [Database Name],   
                       SUM([Total Size in Mb]) AS [Total Size in Mb],   
                       SUM([Available Space in Mb]) AS [Available Space in Mb],   
                       SUM([Total Size in Mb]-[Available Space in Mb]) AS [Consumed Space in Mb]    
                   FROM ##Results   
                   WHERE ##Results.[File Type] = 'Log'   
                       AND [Database Name] = @Database_Name   
                   GROUP BY [Database Name]   
                   ) AS L ON T.[Database Name] = L.[Database Name]   
               ORDER BY D.[Database Name]   
           END   
       ELSE   
           BEGIN   
               SELECT [Database Name],   
               [File Name],   
               [Physical Name],   
               [File Type],   
               [Total Size in Mb] AS [DB Size (Mb)],   
               [Available Space in Mb] AS [DB Free (Mb)],   
               CEILING(CAST([Available Space in Mb] AS decimal(10,1))/[Total Size in Mb]*100) AS [Free Space %],   
               [Growth Units],   
               [Max File Size in Mb] AS [Grow Max Size (Mb)]    
               FROM ##Results    
               WHERE [Database Name] = @Database_Name   
           END   
   END   
DROP TABLE ##Results
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can connect to all these instances directly, you could try some sort of C# utility running locally that connects to the servers, runs the stored procedure, gets the results, and then displays it to you.

Comment: And Powershell can do anything C# can do, and doesn't require a compiler.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The reason I recommended C# was because I believe it handles asynchronous operations a bit more elegantly, but I'll admit my PowerShell-fu is not as good as it should be - I could be mistaken :)

Comment: While there's no async/await language support in PowerShell you can use the Task API directly.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. It's certainly something I will look into, but I am suspecting I may face issues because a number of servers are behind a DMZ and external access through a client app isn't always possible.

Comment: @Asher no problem! IMHO, if you're unable to connect directly, unable to connect via linked servers, and the IT department can't/won't help you, you may be sort-of out of luck. Someone else will hopefully have a better answer, though!